# Are translation requests from German allowed?  /  Sind Fragen nach Übersetzungen aus dem Deutschen erlaubt?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, translation

According to the FAQ, translation requests *to* German are on topic.  No source language is specified there.  But what about *from* German, especially from German to English.  Questions such as [this](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/812/wie-ubersetzt-man-schwerpunktmassig-ins-englische) are [not allowed](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/726/how-would-you-feel-about-allowing-questions-in-foreign-languages-and-translation) on *English Language and Usage*.

> Übersetzungen von Deutsch nach Englisch sind auf *English Language and Usage* (EL&U) [nicht erlaubt](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/726/how-would-you-feel-about-allowing-questions-in-foreign-languages-and-translation). Sollten diese hier erlaubt sein?

Comment: The FAQ is just a copy of the definition phase. I propose that people vote on my answers (or add some) and then we can change the FAQ if appropriate.

Answer (score 25):

I would suggest that you do *not* provide rudimentary "Can you translate this?" services on this site. This is not a translation service; There are better tools for that job.

Translations will be a natural part of this site, but **only as long at they they involve questions about the "finer points of the language."**

There are difficult-to-translate phrases and certain idioms that do not "translate well" across language barriers. I fully support translation requests of this nature. But I would highly suggest that you do not accept question in the form:

> Can you translate this for me?
>
> > Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eros dui, mattis a mattis in, consequat non nisl. Nam condimentum, orci in ornare dapibus, ipsum diam ultrices odio, sit amet volutpat justo odio vel magna.
> >
> > Blah, blah, blah...

Questions of "[**General Reference**](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/939/how-to-respond-to-dictionary-general-reference-questions)" should be closed. There are real people behind this site answering questions, and this site *has* to remain interesting to them — or **they'll go elsewhere.** Once the site devolves into "How do you say 'dog' in German?", you've lost your core audience.

Comment: Very true, good points.

Comment: yeah, we aren't here to do the homework of students.

Comment: This is not what this question is about. People have wanted to close questions for the sole reason that the FAQ says that only one translation direction is allowed. Other people have indeed expressed "Go to ELU to post this." even though ELU does not accept these questions. The complexity issue is independent of this.

Comment: I don't disagree with the detail of this answer, but I don't think it's totally clear that it's saying "yes we should change the FAQ".  Is it saying that?  Also I am not entirely comfortable with the "general reference" close reason.  In order to close a question you need to be able to say "yes/no" it should be closed, rather than have a nebulous complexity threshold.  I would rather deal with "How do you say 'dog' in German?" by downvoting (peer pressure) but maybe that's wishful thinking... maybe we do just need to clearly define what translations are acceptable.

Comment: @Robert Cartino Where are those better tools to translate into English? In most cases I want help with the translation of a question into English it is because I want to properly formulate a question or answer on some other stack exchange site.

Answer (score 11):

There are 2 possible reasons to ask for a translation into Englisch: Because one doesn't understand the german term or is not sure enough about it, or because the person is unsure about English.

So in the first case, the question is alright here, but in the second it isn't, because then you're searching for help with English.

A [good example is the 'Anstrich'-question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1807/how-to-translate-anstrich-in-draw-wrinting-context-into-english), imho. The asking person knows the german word, but searches for an english one, and that is off topic.

---

Es gibt m.E. zwei Gründe, nach einer Übersetzung ins Englische zu suchen: Weil man die deutsche Phrase nicht oder nicht sicher versteht, oder weil man des Englischen nicht so mächtig ist.

Und im ersten Fall ist die Frage m.E. hier richtig, aber im zweiten Fall nicht, weil man dann das englische Wort sucht.

Ein [gutes Beispiel ist die 'Anstrich'-Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1807/how-to-translate-anstrich-in-draw-wrinting-context-into-english). Der Frager kennt das deutsche Wort, aber sucht ein englisches, und das ist hier nicht Thema.

Comment: Die "Anstrich-Frage" ist aber nicht geschlossen worden. Das heißt dann wohl, dass Ihre hier geäußerte Meinung nicht mit der allgemeinen SE Politik übereinstimmt.

Answer (score 2):

Translation requests from German to English are not welcome here and should be closed.

Fragen nach einer Übersetzung von Deutsch auf Englisch sind hier nicht willkommen und sollten geschlossen werden.

Answer (score 0):

Translation requests from German to English are welcome here.

Fragen nach einer Übersetzung von Deutsch auf Englisch sind hier willkommen.

Comment: +1 Looking at http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions vs http://stackoverflow.com/questions the discussion goes more the line which question belongs where. Here when EL&U will not have some questions, there is no reason not to allow them here. In case the number of questions becomes really disturbing, that just would indicate that there might be a critical mass to spin of a site for translation DE to EN.

Comment: I understand that you are trying to make this process easier by providing all possible responses for voting, but, in my experience, this approach is typically counter-productive to your goals. **Users would rather provide their *own* feedback.** Pre-arranged answers encourage neither voting nor feedback and the whole process falls on deaf ears. That's just my experience; Polling is rarely a good way to work out these issue.

Answer (score 0):

Single-word/phrase translation requests from German to English should be welcomed here, since it is a way of explaining meaning.

Translation requests from German to other languages should *not* be welcomed here, since our target audience is English- and German-speaking. See also: [Is it sensible to take the asker's mother-tongue into account?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46/is-it-sensible-to-take-the-askers-mother-tongue-into-account)

Answer (score -1):

Translation requests from German to English are tolerated here until EL&U accepts them as they should, as we accept translations to German.

Fragen nach einer Übersetzung von Deutsch auf Englisch werden hier toleriert bis EL&U sie akzeptiert, wie sie es ja tun sollen, so wie wir hier auch Übersetzungen ins Deutsche übernehmen.

Comment: Heißt das, dass es ein Ultimatum an EL&U gibt? Wissen die ob ihren Glücks? Wenn die wissen, dass wir das übernehmen - wieso sollten sie es dann tun? Ist für Französisch, Portugisisch, Spanisch, Italienisch, Latein, Russisch und Chinesisch ähnliches geplant?

Comment: @user unknown: Kannst du dich klarer ausdrücken? Wo siehst du ein Ultimatum? Ist dein Punkt, dass wir Fragen, die wir problemlos beantworten können, nicht beantworten sollen, um den Leidensdruck zu erhöhen? Ist dir der Gedanke gekommen, dass die Leute, die gerne Übersetzungen von Deutsch auf Englisch wollen, *dieselben* Leute sind, die hier von Englisch auf Deutsch übersetzen?

Comment: Mir ist der Gedanke gekommen, dass ich als Deutsch-Muttersprachler die angemessene, deutsche Übersetzung für ein engl. Wort kennen kann, aber dass die angemessene engl. Übersetzung für ein dt. Wort hier nicht hingehört. Ich bin auch die gleiche Person auf SE, auf U&L, auf AU und 5 weiteren Bereichen, und dennoch sind dort Fragen zur Deutschen Sprache nicht angemessen. Es geht nicht darum einen Leidensdruck zu erhöhen, sondern darum, die Dinge richtig einzusortieren. Wenn man auf EL&U der Meinung ist, solche Übersetzungen seien themenfremd, dann ist das deren Entscheidung.

Comment: Soll man jetzt mal ausprobieren, was passiert, wenn man eine Seite 'Translate any language into English' auf Aera51 viorschlägt, da bin ich mir ziemlich sicher, dass die EL&U Leute mitreden wollen. Irgendwie glaube ich da nicht, das 'Translations' die Lösung bringen wird.

Comment: It seems that the 'No-translation into English' rule in EL&U isn't just an internal matter of that site but influenced by 'higher' instances http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/.  Currently the proposed site 'Languages' is open for translations from any language to any language and it seems to be more promising to commit and promote that site, than to wait for EL&U to change their rules.

Comment: @bernd_k please help me find that site, I can help!

Answer (score -3):

I'd suggest to only translate into German and English as they are preferred languages here to ask questions and to answer them. So if you need a specific word or phrase to answer the question correctly in the language it was asked, why not asking it here?

Answer (score -6):

Translation requests from German to any language are welcome here.

Fragen nach einer Übersetzung von Deutsch in eine beliebige andere Sprache sind hier willkommen.