# Are transcript requests on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

There have been some requests for transcripts recently. I assume they are off topic, by the same token as spell checking individual translations. But I want to be sure, before exercising any moderation duties.

And if so, should we update our FAQs?

My question is prompted by this post: [Long Transcript Request](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/31780/16039)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In these cases the general interest on both, the question, and the answer is low. It is unlikely that any such long or very long transcripts will help future visitors. I believe it is *proofreading* of an individual text, which we said was **off topic**.

The [existing custom close reason](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/926/these-are-our-new-custom-close-reasons) can also be use for these transcription requests.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the "proofreading of individual text" is a proper close reason here - The movie scene referred to is in Berlin Dialect and very hard to understand for any non-native, a dictionary will definitely not help much here. Also, the referred question shows quite a bit of own research effort, the dialogue is already halfway translated.

I do agree, however, that general interest on both question and answer would be low, but that is true or at least disputable for a lot of questions here.

Comment: If we allowed transcripts for proof-reading we should make very clear where  they are different to translations, or to essays presented to us for proof-reading. We should also be clear to what maximum length we will accept them. It feel that a short transcript of a single or only few sentences may be better accepted.