# New audience-specific texts for our custom close reasons

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons

## Background

With [recent changes to the closing system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346638/255554), we can now tailor the texts for custom close reasons to different audiences:

- One text that informs close flaggers, voters, and reviewers when the close reason should be used.
- One brief text that describes the close reason to everybody seeing the question. (It also gets shown in the two following cases.)
- One text to guide the author of a question with improving it, getting help elsewhere, or similar.
- One text to guide users with the [close privilege](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) how to improve the question or guide the asker.

I think this is great since we do not have to have a single text that works on all occasions anymore and have more room for tailored guidance and being more welcoming.

## What happened

I worked together with the other moderators to make use of this system.
One of the close reasons (“Can as well be answered by a dictionary, thesaurus, or conjugation table”) was a test balloon that went active a few days ago.
The others went active just now.
The changes retroactively apply to old questions closed with the respective predecessor close reason.

## Why did you not ask us earlier?

The new texts should not contain any surprises; they reflect existing policy.
Since there is more room and the texts are more targetted, there is little risk of the result being accidentally worse than the status quo.
Also, it is rather difficult to grasp which text goes where without seeing the result in action; I got a few things wrong at first myself.
I therefore considered it better to have you review the result in place, and suggest changes if necessary.

## This question

I’ll post one answer for each of our custom close reasons containing all the texts.
Please use comments to suggest improvements and similar.
Should any complex issues or disagreements arise, I will create separate questions as needed.

---

*Putting this on [status-review](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-review) to get [this](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/1587/revisions) (Revision 2) and [this](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/1589/revisions) (Revision 2) minor change suggested in comments implemented.*

Comment: How should we vote un these options?

Comment: @Wolf: You do not necessarily have to. You can rather point out issues or suggest improvements.

Comment: I already suggested an improvement to https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1587/5437

Comment: @Wolf: I noticed and thank you for that.

Comment: *Putting this on [tag:status-review] to get [this](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/1587/revisions) (Revision 2) and [this](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/1589/revisions) (Revision 2) minor change suggested in comments implemented.*

Comment: Made the minor adjustments as requested.

Answer (score 3):

## Can be answered just as well by a dictionary, thesaurus, or conjugation table

**Close reason:**
This text is shown when selecting a reason while flagging or voting to close:

> #### Can be answered just as well by a dictionary, thesaurus, or conjugation table
>
> The only answers we can post to this question reproduce a dictionary entry or similar. The question neither elaborates why such a resource did not help **nor** is it obvious. Do not vote to close questions only because they can be answered by grammar books. Also see [this FAQ for close voters](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1103).

**General post notice:**
This text is shown under a closed question to everybody:

> **Closed.** This question [can be answered just as well by a dictionary, thesaurus, or conjugation table](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/628). This question is currently not accepting answers.

**Post-owner guidance:**
This text is shown under the general post notice to the author of a question:

> You probably already consulted a dictionary or similar. Please **edit** your question to tell us *what* you found there and *why* that did not help you. Otherwise we cannot help you more than these resources do. Please also read: [How do I ask good, on-topic questions about meaning, translations, or differences?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/628)

**Privileged-user guidance:**
This text is shown under the general post notice to user with the [close privilege](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions):

> If you think you understand the asker’s confusion or can demonstrate that dictionaries or similar do not answer this question, please edit the question to elaborate it. Do not assume that the asker is lazy; they probably did consult a dictionary or similar but just did not tell us about it.

Comment: In the close reason, "nor is it obvious" refers to "such a resource did not help", not to "the question". This could be expressed more clearly.

Comment: @Uwe: I see your point. So far the best way I see to address this is to repeat “why it did not help”. I would avoid the rather uncommon inversion “Neither does the question elaborate why such a resource did not help nor is it obvious.” I am open for better suggestions though.

Comment: Full disclosure: I'm not too active on this site. But the phrasing "can as well be answered by [...]" seems off to me. Perhaps the phrasing "can be adequately answered by [...]" or "can be answered just as well by [...]" (or "can be answered simply by [...]") would sound better/more natural. (Or maybe it's just me that thinks the phrasing sounds strange.)

Comment: Guidiance proposal "You have probably already consulted a dictionary or similar. Please **edit** your question to tell us *what* you found there and *why* that didn't help you. Otherwise, we will not be able to help you more than these resources." ("what" and "why" in italics, "that didn't" instead of "it did not")

Answer (score 3):

## Bulk proofreading or translation request

**Close reason:**
This text is shown when selecting a reason while flagging or voting to close:

> #### Bulk proofreading or translation request
>
> This question asks for the translation, proofreading, or spell checking of a text. It does not ask for help with a single issue within that text. Phrases, idioms, and similar [are such single issues](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1093/2594); questions on them are welcome in general, i.e., unless they should be closed for a different reason.

**General post notice:**
This text is shown under a closed question to everybody:

> **Closed:** This question asks for [translating or proofreading a text](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/919). It is currently not accepting answers.

**Post-owner guidance:**
This text is shown under the general post notice to the author of a question:

> Please **edit** your question to focus on a *single* specific point of concern. Is there a specific term that you do not know how to translate or a specific part that you fear to be incorrect? Also [please tell us](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/628) why a dictionary or similar did not help you. If necessary, ask separate questions about different points of concern. Please see [this post on Meta](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/919) for more information.

**Privileged-user guidance:**
This text is shown under the general post notice to user with the [close privilege](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions):

> If you can identify a likely single point of concern, please edit the question to focus on it. Otherwise help the asker to do this and vote to reopen the question if it has been salvaged.

Answer (score 3):

## Needs expertise in a language other than German

**Close reason:**
This text is shown when selecting a reason while flagging or voting to close:

> #### Needs expertise in a language other than German
>
> This is a translation request to German where the problem is understanding the term in the source language **or** this is a translation request from German where understanding the German term is not the problem (and its meaning is not so intricate that it’s difficult to describe with other words). Also see [this FAQ for close voters](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1103).

**General post notice:**
This text is shown under a closed question to everybody:

> **Closed.** This question [requires expertise in a language other than German](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1057/2594). It is currently not accepting answers.

**Post-owner guidance:**
This text is shown under the general post notice to the author of a question:

> Please **edit** your question to clarify where you need expertise in the German language. For example, can you describe what you want to say in German in English or with more words? If you need expertise in another language, please ask on a site about that language. For further guidance, please read: [Does my translation request belong here and if not, where and how shall I ask it?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1057)

**Privileged-user guidance:**
This text is shown under the general post notice to user with the [close privilege](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions):

> If this is a translation request to German, edit the question to explain the meaning of the term in the source language if you can or guide the asker to do this. Vote to reopen the question if it has been salvaged. Otherwise guide the asker to find an appropriate site for their question and adhere to the rules of that site.

Comment: I think the phrase "expertise of" in these texts should actually be "expertise in" – you can benefit from the expertise of someone, but you benefit from their expertise *in* something. So the general post notice should state (emphasis mine): "[...] This question requires **expertise in a language** other than German. [...]" And the post-owner guidance should state (emphasis mine): "[...] clarify where you need **expertise in** the German language. [...]"