# Is asking to translate a short paragraph from English to German on topic here?

Tags: discussion, translation

I want to see if I'm allowed to ask such a question in the main site?

> Would you please translate the following paragraphs into German?
>
> > - a proposal for creating a remote sensing and photogrammeetry Q&A site    in StackExchange Network is in commitment phase now
> > - All the instructions you need to know to be an effective committer to    the remote sensing and photogrammetry proposal in StackExchange
> > - You can also have a look at the homepage and the "definition phase is    over!" page of this google site.
> > - There I've summarized all the efforts from last year and also have    linked  to valuable tutorials which introduce the StackExchange
> >       network and make you more familiar with what I'm trying to do
> > - Let's make a website for remote sensing and photogrammetry real.    Let's all press "commit" button!
>
> I need them to post about [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/90327/remote-sensing-and-photogrammetry?referrer=8G2asYAyI_To9RoVf1VtPg2) in facebook pages that
>   are related to the topic and promote it. Because as you know and as
>   facebook suggests, posts in local languages receive more likes and
>   more attention and so they might be seen by more people.

Comment: See http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/628/how-do-i-ask-good-on-topic-questions-for-translations-or-about-differences. I am having a bit of trouble to understand how the highlighted paragraph relates to the German language. Can you clarify this, please?

Comment: @Takkat I just mean to translate the bulleted paragraphs. I've quoted the whole part to show it's the exact form of the question that I want to ask in the main site

Comment: If you struggle with a translation and have a question about a particular subject, then you can ask about this issue. Provided you show that you've taken effort into answering the question yourself but failed to translate properly, you will receive an answer as opposed to getting your question closed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No,** this type of question is not acceptable.

For some reason I am pressed to find a fully relevant meta-question. However, going by our *de facto* policies, this type of question is typically quickly closed as off-topic with the following reasoning:

> German Language SE is for specific questions of general interest and to help you learn and understand. Thus, requests for **proofreading, spell checking or translations of individual texts** are not a good fit here. If you can, please narrow down your question to a single specific source of concern. See [this post on Meta](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/919/15318) for more information.

One can argue that this type of ‘bulk’ translation request

- is typically never helpful for future visitors or frankly anybody except OP
- often is not clearly answerable — all sorts of variations of a translation are typically equally acceptable; there is no true ‘best’, making it somewhat opinionated
- typically includes a multitude of issues that need to be addressed, making the question rather broad
- show no prior research whatsoever (it basically is ‘do my work for me.’), going against Stack Exchange’s policies

Comment: thanks, I had the same question in [french SE](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/a/620/11584) and they advised me to ask it in [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32596266#32596266). Am I allowed to do the same in German SE chatroom?

Comment: @sepideh **Yes,** that’s fine. In fact, we used to get quite a few of those in chat ^^.