# Questions and their translations / Fragen und ihre Übersetzungen

Tags: feature-request

I've just asked my first question on "German Language and Usage". While I was doing so I asked myself [What language should the questions be written in?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-language-should-the-questions-be-written-in)

In result of beginning to ask this question here on meta I've came across [Are translation requests from German allowed?  /  Sind Fragen nach Übersetzungen aus dem Deutschen erlaubt?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136/are-translation-requests-from-german-allowed-sind-fragen-nach-bersetzungen) and https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/726/how-would-you-feel-about-allowing-questions-in-foreign-languages-and-translation

I see that here will be the one acceppted as the other. But I think that's suboptimal. My English is quite bad, but I'm quite good in my mother tounge. And I suspect that I'm not alone.

So I promote for developing the community in a kind of way which provides much more knowledge to every single user: Every question here should have a appropriate translation which could be activated, shown according to the locale setting of an user or, what I would prefer, in a split-screen like manner.

Every Asker writes his question in the language he prefers and the translations will be provided as community-wikis. Doing so will give the people which are not that familiar with a language the opportunity to participate to the discussions of native speakers.

---

Ich habe hier gerade meine erste Frage auf "German Language and Usage" gestellt. Währenddessen habe ich mir selbst die Frage gestellt [In welcher Sprache sollten die Fragen geschrieben sein?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-language-should-the-questions-be-written-in)

Infolge des Starts diese Frage hier auf Meta kam ich zu [Are translation requests from German allowed?  /  Sind Fragen nach Übersetzungen aus dem Deutschen erlaubt?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136/are-translation-requests-from-german-allowed-sind-fragen-nach-bersetzungen) und https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/726/how-would-you-feel-about-allowing-questions-in-foreign-languages-and-translation.

Ich sehe dass hier die eine genauso akzeptiert wird wie die andere. Aber ich finde das suboptimal. Mein Englisch ist recht schlecht, dafür kann ich meine Muttersprache recht gut. Und ich schätze, dass ich damit nicht allein bin.

Daher möchte ich für die Entwicklung der Gemeinschaft in einer Art werben, welche mehr Wissen für jeden einzelnen Nutzer mit sich bringt: Für jede Frage sollte es eine entsprechende Übersetzung geben, die aktiviert werden kann, die entsprechend der Spracheinstellungen des Browsers oder, was ich bevorzugen würde, in einer zweigeteilten Ansicht angezeigt wird.

Jeder Fragesteller schreibt seine Frage in seiner bevorzugten Sprache und die Übersetzung wird durch Gemeinschafts-Wikis zur Verfügung gestellt. Auf diese Art wird Menschen mit weniger Sprachkenntnissen die Möglichkeit geboten an Diskussionen von Muttersprachlern (hässliches Wort - ich weiss) teilzuhaben.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have voted for a primary usage of German in different aspects:

- for questions and answers
- for the user interface
- for meta
- for tags

There was a strict requierement from the ownerside, that meta has to stay english, because most moderators don't speak German. I don't think that this is a good argument, since few meta-discussions can be moderated without being able to read the main page, where German is allowed.

Another problem is with the tags, which are forced to be lowercase, if I remember correctly.

For the user interface, there is a thread about plugins in firefox, which everybody may use. I participated a little in searching for best translations, but there was nearly no feedback, and so the thing felt into sleep. Personally, I don't need translations for the UI, so there is not much motivation on my side.

In my opinion, this side (not meta, but main) should be for everybody interested in German, not only in people who are able to talk in English: French, Russian, Chinese, Arabian, ... And if you learn a foreign language, you normally do it in that language. We can't teach people German from scratch here.

So if I have a question, I ask it in German only, and if I have an answer, I answer in German. Only if somebody explicitly asks for an English answer, I might answer in English.

But I can't write Arabian, Chinese, Russian and nearly no French.

**tl;dr** Bilinual answering isn't always possible, english isn't helpful for everybody, and who want's to learn German will be thankful, if he can practice while visiting us.

---

Ich habe mich schon verschiedentlich für eine primär deutsche Seite ausgesprochen, für:

- Fragen und Antworten
- die statischen Seiteneelemente
- Meta
- Schlagworte

Es gab einen kompromisslosen Einspruch seitens der Betreiber bezüglich Meta. Die meisten Moderatoren könnten kein Deutsch. Dies erscheint mir kein gutes Argument, da nur wenige Metadiskussionen moderiert werden können, ohne dass man die Hauptseiten liest, auf denen Deutsch toleriert wird. (Zweisprachige Seiten auf Meta sind OK.)

Soweit ich weiß sind die Tags automatisch in Kleinschreibweise, was auf Deutsch zu Konflikten führt und falsch wäre.

Für die Benutzerschnittstelle gibt es einen Diskussionsfaden über ein Plugin für Firefox, das man benutzen kann. Ein wenig habe ich mich mit Übersetzungsversuchen engagiert doch die Aktivität schlief rasch ein, da es kaum Rückmeldungen oder andere Interessierte gab, und da ich mit der Seite zurechtkomme ist meine Motivation auch überschaubar.

Nach meiner Meinung sollten die Hauptseiten sich an jeden richten, der Deutsch lernen will, unabhängig ob er schon Englisch kann. Franzosen, Russen, Chinesen, Araber, ... Und wo immer man Sprachen lernt, man lernt sie in der Sprache. Wir können den Leuten nicht Deutsch von der Pike auf beibringen.

Wenn ich eine Frage habe, stelle ich sie auf Deutsch. Und ich antworte auch auf Deutsch, außer jemand erbittet ausdrücklich englische Antworten,

Aber ich kann gar nicht auf Arabisch, Chinesisch, Russisch oder Französisch antworten.

**summa summarum:** Zweisprachig zu antworten geht nicht immer, Englisch nützt nicht immer, und wer Deutsch lernen will, weil er es noch nicht kann sollte dankbar sein, wenn er nebenbei Deutsch im praktischen Gebrauch lernt.

Comment: There are good arguments which yesterday I couldn't make out for my own. The proposal is hereby cancelled. --- Das sind gute Argumente, auf die ich gestern nicht gekommen bin. Der Vorschlag ist hiermit offiziell zurückgezogen.

Comment: About lowercase (and btw., umlauts and other diacritics) in tags, https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1497/zweisprachige-tags-oder-zweisprachig-angezeigte-tags-bilingual-tags-or-bilingu could help.